# How to call a javascript function from php within a html field

Tags: php, jquery, function, checkbox, jscript

```
<div>

 <input  type="checkbox" id="paypal" name="paypal"  value=" "  <?php if ($paypal="yes"): ?> checked="checked"  <?php echo '<script type="text/javascript">','chbx(this);','</script>'; ?> <?php endif; ?>  onclick="chbx(this);" ></input>

    <label for="paypal" id='paypal2' class="checkboxes" >Show PayPal Accepted <?php echo $paypal; ?></label>
<br>

<input   type="checkbox" id="facebook"  name="facebook"  value=" "  <?php if ($facebook="yes"):  ?>  checked="checked"  <?php endif; ?>   onclick='chbx(this);' >
</input>
<label for="facebook" id='facebook2' class="checkboxes"  >Show FaceBook Contact Details</label>

<br>

<input   type="checkbox" id="twitter"  name="twitter"  value=" "    <?php if ($twitter="yes"):  ?> checked="checked" <?php endif; ?>   onclick='chbx(this);' >
</input>
<label for="twitter" id='twitter2' class="checkboxes"  >Show Twitter Contact Details</label>
</div>



<div id='paypal1'  class='listfooterinfo' ><span style='color:blue;'>PayPal Accepted:</span>An Icon Will Let Your Buyers Know You Accept PayPal For Payments</div>
<div id='facebook1' class='listfooterinfo'><span style='color:blue;'>Facebook Contact:</span> An Icon Will Allow Buyers To Contact You Via Facebook</div>
<div id='twitter1'  class='listfooterinfo'><span style='color:blue;'>Twitter Contact:</span>An Icon Will Allow Buyers To Contact You Via Twitter</div>



<script>        
    function chbx(obj) {


       var that = obj;

    if(document.getElementById(that.id).checked === true) 

        {
        document.getElementById(that.id).checked = true;
        document.getElementById(that.id).value='yes';
        document.getElementById(that.id+"1").classList.add("listfooterinfoin");



        } 

    else 

        {
        document.getElementById(that.id).checked === false 
        document.getElementById(that.id).checked = false;
        document.getElementById(that.id).value='no';
        document.getElementById(that.id+"1").classList.remove("listfooterinfoin");

        }

    }

</script>
```

Can Anybody Tell Me Why Instead Of Calling The Function chbx(this); It Just Echo's As Plain Text On My Page

```
"
<?php if ($paypal="yes"): ?> checked="checked"  <?php echo '<script type="text/javascript">','chbx(this);','</script>'; ?> <?php endif; ?> 
"
```

echo's out instead of calling the function

Im trying to call the function if $paypal="yes" and checkbox="checked" to add a class to a footer, but i cannot get the footer to addclass, instead its just echoing out text..

any ideas.

Or Can Anybody point me in the right direction to add the class if the checkbox is checked because $paypal="yes".

The addclass basically makes visible the text..

But even though the checkboxes are checked, the class is not addedd to show the text, it is only added when i click on the checkbox because the function is then called through onclick, but i need the function to be called to addclass if the box is checked because of the $paypal='yes'..

So basically i need to call the function when $paypal makes checkbox="checked" so the text will display.

Any ideas.

Long winded i know.  But iv been up all night trying to figure it out and iv scratched holes in my head...

Thanks in advance.

Mel.

p.s i also tried this way, but no luck

```
 $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {  
     if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        chbx(this);
        chbxB(this);
        chbxF(this);
     }
      else {
        // remove the items 
     }
    });
```

Comment: you need to wrap those js functions inside `<script></script>` tags, like `<script> your js code here </script>`

Comment: you do you write `<script type="text/javascript">','chbx(this);','</script>` in the input field ? 
you cannot do like that.

`onclick="chbx(this);` is enough for the input tag.
Write your if else condition whether to print `onclick` or not. That's enough.
At the end of the page, inside script tags you must define your function. Like this:
`<script>
 function chbx(var)
{
  // write your code here
}
</script>`

Comment: because i need to call the function if $paypal="yes" and checkbox="checked"  the onclick is for when user clicks checkbox,  the php $ is setting the checkbox according to a post variable from another page.

Comment: p.s there is <script> tags in the code, b4 and after, i just did not add them in the re-write example